# inno setup- Passing File path as a command line parameter

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am passing a set of parameters from main setup through the command line which also includes file paths and reading the values in Subsetup. The command line parameters output looks like below

```
/dir="D:\XXX.Web" /dbname="XXX" /dbinstancename="XXX" /dbsapwd="123!"#$%" /dataFileDirectory="D:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\DATA" /logFileDirectory="D:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\Log" /backupDirectory="E:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\Backup" /sqlCmdLocation="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" /webappname="yyyy" /Nameservice="VVVV" /UserUsername="user"
```

I am getting the parameter values in the Subsetup using a custom GetParameter function and storing in the String like mentioned below...

```
// This is how I get the values and store in String
DBName := GetParameter('/dbname=', DBName);
DataFileDirectory := GetParameter('/dataFileDirectory=', DataFileDirectory);

// function to get the parameters from the commandline parameters
    function GetParameter(ParamName, Default: String): String;
var
    P, I: Integer;
begin
    Result := Default;
    if Length(ParamName) < 1 then Exit;
    ParamName := Lowercase(ParamName);
    for I := 2 to ParamCount() do begin
        P := pos(ParamName, Lowercase(ParamStr(I)));
        if P > 0 then begin
            P := P + Length(ParamName);
            Result := Copy(ParamStr(I), P, Length(ParamStr(I))+1-P);
            Result := Trim(RemoveQuotes(Trim(Result)));
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

When I print all the  values in the log file, I am getting the output like mentioned below.

```
    DBName = XXX
    DBSaPwd = ********
    DBInstanceName = XXX
    DataFileDirectory = D:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\DATA /logFileDirectory=D:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\Log /backupDirectory=E:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\Backup /sqlCmdLocation=C:\Program
    LogFileDirectory = D:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\Log /backupDirectory=E:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\Backup /sqlCmdLocation=C:\Program
    BackupDirectory = E:\MSSQL10_50.XXX\MSSQL\Backup /sqlCmdLocation=C:\Program
    SqlCmdLocation = C:\Program
    WebAppName = yyyy /Nameservice=VVVV /UserUsername=user /UserPassword=user /MSSQLServerSelection= /silent /restart=false
```

The file path value of **DataFileDirectory** for example is taking the next parameter values and so on for the subsequent values which is throwing "**File name, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect**" error at the end of the setup execution.

I believe an escape sequence must be used to solve this problem. Please provide your suggestions to solve this error and to implement it correctly.

Thanks in advance

DeeJay

Comment: Do not post fake or incomplete code.

Comment: Hi, I just replaced the sensitive values. The code snippet and the problem is here as it happened.

Comment: There is no such thing like `ParamString`, so you are hiding something from us. Couldn't we get a minimal compilable script, please ? That would save the time for all.

Comment: My apologies @TLama, I ve updated the correct function in the code now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Well, the problem is in the `ParamStr` parsing of the `/dbsapwd` parameter value. To be more specific in its double quote char.

Comment: @TLama, you are right. It is a database password. Is the GetParameter function required to be changed to handle this or how can I proceed?

Comment: To make it work you must either double all double quotes (`"` → `""`) in parameter values (that is you pass `/dbsapwd="123!""#$%"`), or stop using `ParamStr` and parse the command line by yourself. I would do the first if it's only you who's supposed to execute that subsetup (knowing about that double-double quoting).

Comment: Thanks a lot TLama, I suspected the '/' in the file path for this issue. I ll make the changes accordingly..

Comment: Nope, it was a single double quote in the value. Slashes are handled properly as long as you enclose values in double quotes. Finally, one debugging hint. If you're aware of using debugger, you can set the parameters through the *Run | Parameters* menu in the IDE. That way you can run your setup in debugger passing the parameters you set there.